# Trouble understanding bit shifting as follows

Tags: c, bit, masking

So I have written the code below which takes an unsigned int , shifts its bits 6 positions to the left then replaces the empty final 6 bits with another int value. However, when I run the code say with value 15, the first step works and I get a value of 960 (so shifting left by 6 works). But the or step does not seem to work and I get -1 when I actually need to get 1111111111111111 or i.e. 65535 (note the operand value in this case is -1)? Any help would be greatly appreciated. I understand it is something to maybe do with my types but s->data was defined as an unsigned int whilst operand is defined as an int so I do not know why the output of s->data gives a negative value.

```
typedef struct state { int x, y, tx, ty; unsigned char tool; unsigned int start, data; bool end;} state;

void dataCommand(int operand, state *s) {
    // shifts bits of current data fields six positions to left
    printf("BEFORE SHIFTING %d\n", s->data);
    s->data = s->data << 6;
    printf("AFTER SHIFTING %d\n", s->data);
    printf("OPERAND IS %d\n", operand);
    // last 6 bits replaced with operand bits of the command
    s->data = (s->data | operand);
    printf("AFTER OR %d\n", s->data);

}
```

Comment: If your `operand` is `-1` that means all bits are set in two's complement representation. It does not matter what value is stored in `s->data` as all bits will be set afterwards anyway.

Comment: Is your `unsigned int` 16 bit long? Then `-1` is the very same as `65535` when it comes to binary representation. It is 16 bit all set to 1. The difference is just to tell your compiler treat it as signed or unsigned value.

Comment: Please edit your question to include all required type definitions, the way you call your function and how you print results. Don't just describe it but show the code. See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more details about what is expected.

Comment: You are printing `unsigned int` values using `%d`. You should use `%u`, or even better for visualising bits, `%x` or `%X`.

Comment: Print as hexadecimal instead, it makes it easier to "see" the bit patterns. Or create a function to print the actual binary representation to make it even more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `operand` is -1 it is actually `0xffffffff` (32 ones in binary).
So when you are ORing you get back 32 ones which is still -1.

Maybe what you wanted to do was masking 6 bits off the operand :

```
s->data = (s->data << 6) | (operand & 0b111111);
```

Comment: thanks this works but i get the following warning : warning: binary integer literals are a GNU extension
      [-Wgnu-binary-literal].

Comment: is there a way to remove this warning ?

Comment: You could replace `0b111111` (6 ones) by `127` or `0x3f` but then the code doesn't speak for itself, if you often manipulate bits I would suggest to disable the warning in your compiler settings, switch standard or just ignore it.

Comment: @Scouarn.: `0x3F` is `63`, not `127`. A more explicit expression such as `((1U << 6) - 1)` might be more reliable indeed or `~(~0U << 6)`

Comment: @chqrlie Indeed, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

You must mask the `operand` to select which bits are combined into the result.

`-1` is converted to `unsigned int` in the `s->data | operand` expression, to the value `UINT_MAX` that has all bits set, hence oring `operand` sets all bits in the result, giving it a value of `UINT_MAX`, but since you use `%d` to output the value, you get `-1`.

Modify the code this way:

```
typedef struct state {
    int x, y, tx, ty;
    unsigned char tool;
    unsigned int start, data;
    bool end;
} state;

void dataCommand(int operand, state *s) {
    // shifts bits of current data fields six positions to left
    printf("BEFORE SHIFTING %u\n", s->data);
    s->data = s->data << 6;
    printf("AFTER SHIFTING %u\n", s->data);
    printf("OPERAND IS %d (%#x)\n", operand, operand);
    // last 6 bits replaced with operand bits of the command
    s->data = s->data | (operand & 0x3F);
    printf("AFTER OR %u\n", s->data);
}
```